# Trace route walking or driving in android google maps api v2 using not deprecated methods

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I want to make this task and I´ve found some libraries to do that [here by tyczj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20332453/4987172) and [here by akexorcist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053948/4987172). These are good solutions but this libraries use httpClient and currently is deprecated, is there others?. Thanks.

It could be useful.

Comment: [akexorcist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554078/is-there-a-way-to-show-road-directions-in-google-map-api-v2/15053948#15053948) that works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make your own http request to get directions information from [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) and get `overview_polyline` string from response.
2. Decode the string using [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library with `PolyUtil.decode` method.
3. Add decoded points to map:

   ```
   List<LatLng> decodedPoints = PolyUtil.decode(polylineString);
   PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
   options.width(6);
   options.color(Color.RED);
   options.addAll(decodedPoints);

   map.addPolyline(options);
   ```

Comment: I´ve been reading docs but i don´t know how to put the new Api key from this Direction Api cause I have already API KEY for maps